# how to input data of type maps

Tags: node, ligo

[image: I tried putting the above data to interact but it don't worked]

This is a multiasset holding contract with code to mint and burn FA2 tokens but I am confused ion how to provide the inputs as it is getting errored token_info is the metadata section I want to put metadata there. To test yourself pls got to
https://better-call.dev/ithacanet/KT1DHjj4FnizYuFprC6B1NWvFTQg3EcuV5ZC/interact/mint

Comment: You cannot use BCD that way it takes single parameters only, you are trying to inject code instead of sending parameters

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from `x as nat` and `"hello"`. It should be `x` without `as nat` and `hello` without quotes.